# jquery on 'click' not working on generated class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class of 'this' when you click on an li, and when you click on a class with '.this' it doesnt work.

Even when i use the .on method it doesnt work. What am i missing? this is driving me crazy.

```
var thisLi = $('ul li');

$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(thisLi).removeClass('that');
    $(thisLi).removeClass('this');
    $(this).addClass('this');
});


$('li.this').on("click", "li.this", function() {
    $(this).addClass('that');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zfda8145/2/

Comment: I think when you click on the li.this, the first click handler is going to remove the 'this' class, and the second li.this click handler will never be called. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation for that. Because normal event binding will not bind the event to the future elements. For that, you need to bind the events to a particular parent. Here I am using `document`

```
$(document).on("click", "li.this", function() {
    $(this).addClass('that');
 });
```

Comment: thanks it kind of helps, but now both of these functions are running,
$('li.this').on("click", "li.this", function() {
    $(this).addClass('that');
 });
and
$(document).on("click", "li.this", function() {
    $(this).addClass('that');
 });

should i be using an if statement to check if it hasclass?

Answer (score 0):

This snipplet should do the trick.
First you need to grab the `ul` element - to avoid searching shole DOM for ul.
Secondly you apply `click` event on it's elements:)

```
    var thisLi = $('ul li');
    var list = $('ul');
    list.on('click','li', function() {
        $(thisLi).removeClass('that');
        $(thisLi).removeClass('this');
        $(this).addClass('this');
    });


    list.on('click','li.this', function() {
        $(this).addClass('that');
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var thisLi = $('ul');

    $('li').on('click', function() {
        $(thisLi).removeClass('that');
        $(thisLi).removeClass('this');
        $(this).addClass('this');
    });


    $(thisLi).on("click","li.this", function() {
        $(this).addClass('that');
     });
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zfda8145/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that kind of thing :

```
var thisLi = $('ul li');

$('li').on('click', function() {
    if(this.className!=='this'){
    $(thisLi).removeClass('that');
    $(thisLi).removeClass('this');
    $(this).addClass('this');
    }else{
       $(this).addClass('that');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements)

(https://api.jquery.com/on/)

It works when you change this

```
$('li.this').on("click", "li.this", function()
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.this", function()
```

In this logic, you actually determine the scope where `click` event can take place. If you use `$('li.this').on()`, this considers `click` events for only descendants of `li.this` but no descendants exists for `li.this`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you click on this.li, it triggers both functions, first removing the class, and then not executing because the class is gone.

I rewrote it as one function that does class checking instead of separate functions. I don't really like this, but if you are stuck it will get you going.

```
$('li').on('click', function() {    

    if ($(this).hasClass('that')) {
        $(this).removeClass('that');        
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('this')) {
        $(this).addClass('that');
        $(this).removeClass('this');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('this');
    }

});
```

And here is a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zfda8145/24/